# ASP.NET VB how to add image on sqldatabase

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, sqldatasource

Can anybody help me on how to insert an image into a database that can be viewed on a webpage?
or whatever way there is just to do this thing.

I am currently developing a webpage in Web Developer 2008 ASP.NET VB.

Answer (score 0):

You may convert you image to bytes using the below or similar code, and then store the bytes to a database Field. (This is in C#, but I'm sure you can find an online utility to convert it to VB.NET):

```
public byte[] BitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    return ms.ToArray();
    //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, data.Width, data.Height);
    //BitmapData bmdata = data.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    //byte[] pixels=null;
    //Marshal.Copy(bmdata.Scan0, pixels, 0, bmdata.Stride * data.Height);
    //return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pixels);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in database. You have to create a blob field. This is "Binary Large Object" data type which stores binary data. Images are binary data.

[You can check this article on it](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3738276/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server-Part-4.htm) for more reference

[This code project example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19130/Store-and-retrieve-objects-as-BLOBs-in-SQL-Server) will serve you better as well.

You have to convert the image into blob first and back from blob to image when you read it.